# PHP or JS calendar that is capable of importing calendar data like ics or csv files from outlook

Tags: php, csv, calendar, outlook, icalendar

Hope somebody could help me out, I am trying to find a solution for exporting an Outlook Calendar onto a webpage on weekly basis or for amendments.

I know Outlook is capable of exporting a calendar into ICS and CSV files was wondering if there are any products out there that will take me at least half way there.

I have some experience with PHP and JS so feel confident enough to do some modification but it needs to at least import and parse the files.

I have had a look around on the web and found a few tools but nothing as specific as what im looking for.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think you probably had better to write the import by yourself.

These could be the steps:

1. An html page with a form that allow file upload
2. On submit a php page parse csv row by row and eventually do other works you need to display the calendare

Here just a snippet of code that shows ho easily is to manage csv file in php

```
 <?php
 $row = 1;
 if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
     while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
       $num = count($data);
       echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
       $row++;
       for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
    }
  }
  fclose($handle);
 }
?>
```

Comment: thank you for the snippet i will give that a go. in terms of the upload I will go for a WebDAV interface for the user so that it is easy for the to upload

Answer (score 0):

for icalendar compatibility and rendering I could only recomend [phpicalendar](http://phpicalendar.net) .